# How do I add js within another directory in my assets/javascripts/ to the assets.precompile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

In one of my views, I have this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "piggybak_variants/piggybak_variants" %>
```

Which includes a `piggybak_variants.js` file.

I tried this in my `production.rb`

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(piggybak_variants.js)
```

But I am still getting an error in Heroku about that file not being pre-compiled.

How do I fix that, other than doing `*.js`? That seems like using a sledge hammer.

Comment: Where, within your app directory structure, is `piggybak_variants.js` located?

Comment: `\app\assets\javascripts\piggybak_varaints\piggybak_varaints.js`

Comment: Have you tried `config.assets.precompile += %w(piggybak_variants/piggybak_variants.js)`

Comment: Perfect...that works. Thanks! If you add that as an answer, I will accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your include path is missing the parent directory. This should work:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(piggybak_variants/piggybak_variants.js)
```